# symbol lookup error while starting a electron script using serialport

Tags: node.js, npm, serial-port, electron

I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/arrowBank/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/share/nginx/html/arrowBank/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
/usr/share/nginx/html/arrowBank/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by **strong text**/usr/share/nginx/html/arrowBank/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"
selected /dev/ttyUSB1
/usr/share/nginx/html/arrowBank/node_modules/electron/dist/electron .: symbol lookup error: /usr/share/nginx/html/arrowBank/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/bindings.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v811HandleScope12CreateHandleEPNS_8internal10HeapObjectEPNS1_6ObjectE
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! arrowbank@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT`enter code here`
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the arrowbank@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ebuilders/.npm/_logs/2019-07-18T05_55_53_359Z-debug.log
```

Uninstall the serialport and reinstall those serialport but that issue not fixed. My npm version : 6.4.1, node version :10.14.0,serialport version :7.1.5

My code:

```
ipcMain.on('send-selectedPort',(event, arg) =>{
    var selectedPort = arg;
    var port = new serialport(selectedPort, {
    baudRate: 9600,
    autoOpen: false
  });

  if(port){
   port.write('Hello', function(err, res) {
     if (res) {
       console.log("screen Res",res);
     }
     if (err) {
       console.log('Error on write: ', err)
     }
  })
})
```